# How to verify text in a textbox ends with a question mark using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a magic 8 ball web page. A user enters a question in a text box, clicks a button, and there will be a random response generated and displayed. I have two stipulations: I must throw an alert box if the same question is asked twice in a row(completed); and I must throw an alert box if the question does not end with a question mark(halfway there). Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var responses = [];
  responses[0] = "Ask again later...";
  responses[1] = "Yes";
  responses[2] = "No";
  responses[3] = "It appears to be so";
  responses[4] = "Reply is hazy, please try again";
  responses[5] = "Yes, definitely";
  responses[6] = "What is it you really want to know?";
  responses[7] = "Outlook is good";
  responses[8] = "My sources say no";
  responses[9] = "Signs point to yes";
  responses[10] = "Don't count on it";
  responses[11] = "Cannot predict now";
  responses[12] = "As I see it, yes";
  responses[13] = "Better not tell you now";
  responses[14] = "Concentrate and ask again";
  var answer;
  var questionValue;    

  function getRandom(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
  }

  $("input[type=button]").click(function() {
    if ("input[type=text]".substr(-1) != "?") {
      alert("Ask with a question mark at the end");
    } else if(questionValue != $("#txtQuestion").val()) {
      var my_num = getRandom(15);
      var answer = responses[my_num];
      $("#Response").text(answer);
    } else {
      alert("Ask a new question");
    }
    questionValue = $("#txtQuestion").val();
  });
});
```

Before I checked for a question mark, everything worked fine. If I asked the same question twice in a row, it threw out an alert box. But when I try checking for a question mark at the end, it only throws out an alert box saying make sure you end with a question mark, even if there is one at the end. What am I doing wrong?

Updated with HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Magic 8 Ball</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <header>
        <h1>Magic 8 Ball</h1>
      </header>
      <h3>What would you like to know?</h3>
      <input type="text" name="txtQuestion" id="txtQuestion" />
      <br />
      <input type="button" id="btnAsk" value="Ask the 8 Ball" />
      <h3>The 8 Ball says:</h3>
      <h3 id="Response">Ask the 8 Ball a question...</h3>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/my_scripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: add the html code too.

Comment: LOOK AT THE CODE: `"input[type=text]"`

Comment: Yeah it should say look at what is in the input-text field, and go to the end of the string. If there is no question mark there, throw the alert box. But it does even when there is a question mark there. The only thing I can think of is it is doing that because the input box is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a call to `$()`.  You've forgotten to use jQuery to locate `"input[type=text]"` and instead are calling `.substr` on this *literal string*.  `"input[type=text]"` most certainly does not end with a question mark.

-- For the comments --

Somehow, the above is not clear, so I'll include more details.  In this line of code:

```
    if ("input[type=text]".substr(-1) != "?") {
```

You're testing whether the string `"input[type=text]"` ends with a question mark.  That is *never* going to be true.  However, if you were to change it like so:

```
    if ($('#txtQuestion').val().substr(-1) != "?") {
```

You are now testing whether the value of your question field ends with a question mark, which *might* be true at some point.

Comment: I guess I don't quite understand...Do I create a var to hold what the user enters and then check that instead of input[type=text] ?

Comment: @nponinski - Yep, that's pretty exactly it.  Or, if you really don't want the intermediary value, you can operate on `$('#txtQuestion').val()` directly.  But calling `"input[type=text]".substr(-1)` is _always_ going to return `"]"`.

Comment: How would I do that directly? I cannot get this to work

Comment: Ohhhh I see! I did not put the .substr after the .val() You are a lifesaver! Thank you so much!